# Having trouble converting a a hexidecimal into a decimal in Mips

Tags: mips

I've been having trouble converting the given hexadecimal to decimal
in this procedure calls problem using code. I just want to
see and understand the code that converts the hex to dec.

Here's the description of the problem

Description : Write a function "hexint" that takes
the address of an ascii character string in $a0.
The string will represent a number in
hexadecimal and will only contain '0' to '9'
and 'A' to 'F' .
Return the actual number in the register $v0.
Remember that the most significant nibble
will be first in the string .

Output format must be :
" Number is = 1960 "

```
.text
main:

#Display ans String
la $a0, ans
li $v0, 4
syscall

#Store string from data and jump hexint
la $a0, str
jal hexint

#Display modified string
move $a0 , $v0
li $v0, 1
syscall

la $a0, endl
li $v0, 4
syscall

#End
exit:   
1i $v0,10
syscall



#------------ start cut --------------------------

#the jal code here


#------------ end cut ----------------------------


. data
str  :. asciiz " 7A8 "
ans  :. asciiz " Number is
endl :. asciiz " \n"
```

Comment: Can you do this in C or pseudo code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is pretty broad. Where are you stuck, exactly? See [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Thanks.

Comment: I'm stuck on the conversion from the ascii / hexadecimal(7A8) to the decimal (1960) that's supposed to be in the start and end cut segment at the bottom. I know how to convert on paper but not in code format.

Comment: I don't see any code at all in that cut area, so why don't you give it a shot at implementing your code based on your paper algorithm (that's something you could post to make the question more reasonable), then ask a concrete question if you get stuck. The link above says "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed." and "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation." Thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
        .text
    main:

    #Display ans String
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, ans
    syscall

    #Store string from data and jump hexint
    la $a0, str
    jal hexint

    #Display modified string
    move $a0 , $v0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, endl
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    
    
    #End
    exit:   
    li $v0,10
    syscall
    

    #------------ start cut --------------------------

#the jal code here
    hexint:
        
        li $s3,0
        move $a2,$a0
        strlen:

        li $s0, 0 # initialize the count to zero
        strlen_loop:
            lb $t1, ($a0) # load the next character into t1
            beqz $t1, main_loop # check for the null character
            addi $a0, $a0, 1 # increment the string pointer
            addi $s0, $s0, 1 # increment the count
        j strlen_loop # return to the top of the loop
        
    
    main_loop:
        
        #move $s4,$s0
        move $t1,$s0
        subi $t1,$t1,1
    loop:
        
        li $s2,1
                        
        power_loop: 
            blt $t1,1,test   # if 
            mul $s2,$s2,16
            subi $t1,$t1,1
            
        j power_loop
        
        test:
            lb $t3,($a2)
            blt $t3,'A',is_digit   # if char less than 'A' => char is digit according to ascii table
           is_alpha:li $t5,0
            sub $t5,$t3,'A'
            la $a3,array       
            
            mul $t8,$t5,4
            add $a3,$a3,$t8
            lw $t6,($a3)
            j addition
        is_digit:
            andi $t6,$t3,0xf  # allows to convert string "7" to integer 7
        addition:
            mul $s4,$t6,$s2   
            add $s3,$s3,$s4
            addi $a2,$a2,1
            subi $s0,$s0,1
            beqz $s0,finished
            move $t1,$s0
            subi $t1,$t1,1
    j loop
    
    finished:
        move $v0,$s3
        jr $ra
    
    #------------ end cut ----------------------------
    
    

    .data
    str  :.asciiz "5D123"
    ans  :.asciiz " Number is : "
    endl :.asciiz " \n"
    array: .word 10,11,12,13,14,15 #
```